# Why am I unable to install,remove or upgrade packages?

Tags: upgrade, apt, package-management, partial-upgrade, postgresql

When I wanna do anything with Synaptic or `apt-get` or stop,start,restart `postgresql` I  receive following error

```
Setting up postgresql-common (114) ...
 * Starting PostgreSQL 8.4 database server                                       * Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 63.
                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm using ubuntu 11.04 .
I canceled upgrade to 11.10 last night during upgrade,and changed `source.list`, then reload package information from Synaptic. Maybe this is related to the issue in some way, however, I changed `source.list` back to default and reload it again, but, it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: how far through the upgrade did you cancel? 1% 50% 99%?

Comment: @fossfreedom during downloading package,when it downloaded 21 packages of 2762 packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused due to installation of Postgre SQL was stopped in between. Purge the postgre sql installation and you will be fine.

To purge postgre sql installation, in console type

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge postgresql
```

Trying running these commands, it should resolve it.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: it failed,it returned same error during remove

Comment: try doing sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: I did it too,but it will return same problem

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*
```

It helped me. I had same problem. Command differs with suggestion at the end '\*'.